# ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED while publishing using visual studio 201

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-web-deploy

Getting error:

> ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED

while publishing using Visual Studio 2017. Same error I got earlier in case of VS 2015 but I resolved it by putting True in publish profile file. But this is not working for VS 2017. Please suggest.

Comment: See if my answer to this post works, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204925/vs2017-rc-web-deploy-error-certificate-validation-failed/43071492#43071492